# How to determine the best batch-size value for Mini Batch K-means algorithm?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am working on a project where I apply k-means on severals datasets. These datasets may include up to several billion points. I would like to use mini batch k-means to save time. However, the mini batch k-means requires a value for the batch size argument (I am using sklearn). What is the best way to choose a good batch size?

Comment: I'd prefer "real" k-means to minibatch. Have you compared runtime and quality of both?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I used mini batch for data of small size. It is faster than real k-means and it has almost the same quality as the real k-means. I would like to know how to define the best value of the batch size to get almost the same quality but saving a lot of time if I have several billions of points.

Comment: Try regular kmeans with fewer iterations, too, if you want to trade speed for quality. Obviously there is no "best" value that is universal. With larger k you will need much larger batches, for example.

Comment: Also, you can simply cluster just a sample instead, rather than all points... The benefit of mini-batch over sampling is not well studied in my opinion.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse In case of using k-means with sampling how to choose good samples because if we apply real k-means over multiple samples of the same data we may obtain very different results even bad results.

Comment: Supposedly not very different from minibatch samples, what do you think? Of course you shouldn't just sample k points. But if you have k=10 and 1 million points, sampling 10000 may be enough. It may even give you better results if you are lucky to not pick certain outliers, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that minibatch would be better to avoid the outlier. If you believe there is no outlier, then Kmeans should be better.